# Searching in a table using a dynamic sql (stored procedure) in MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, prepared-statement, dynamic-sql, concatenation

I have a table (userTable) with the following columns:
IdUser, Firstname, Id_gender_FK

And a table (genderTable) with the following columns:
Id_gender, GenderName

I want to search through the userTable by dynamic columns and using a searchingtext.
(I choose the column to search in and the searchtext)

This is my  code:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE spX (IN ColumnName VARCHAR(20), IN SearchText VARCHAR(20))
BEGIN

SET @sql = CONCAT(
    'SELECT u.IdUser, u.Firstname, g.GenderName

        FROM userTable AS u

        RIGHT OUTER JOIN genderTable AS g
        ON u.Id_gender_FK= g.Id_gender

        WHERE ', ColumnName, ' LIKE ', SearchText);

        PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
        EXECUTE stmt;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

This is how I call the stored procedure:
CALL spX('Firstname', 'jack');

This is the error I get:
Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'jack' in 'where clause'

I also want to be able to use 'ja' as a searchtext instead of 'jack'. Therefore I have to use the '%' symbol to do this. Fx. ja%, then it should find every result that starts with 'ja'. I can do this in normal sql query, but don't know in stored procedure.

Comment: SearchText should be quoted. Otherwise the database server will assume it's a column name.

Comment: How do you mean by quoted. I have tried using ' " '. E.g. "SearchText" but didn't work. I also tried "jack" instead of 'jack'.

Comment: `WHERE ', ColumnName, ' LIKE "', SearchText, '"' );`

Comment: OMG stupid me...Thank you. Should have been '"jack"'. XD

Comment: Your method also works :D

Comment: @marekful **No.**  SQL injection. Never concatenate quotation marks around variables into a query.  There is a function for this purpose `WHERE ', ColumnName, ' LIKE ', QUOTE(SearchText));` or if you need wildcards `WHERE ', ColumnName, ' LIKE ', QUOTE(CONCAT('%',SearchText,'%'));`